# In htaccess, how do I write a Rewrite (RewriteRule) that only acts under certain conditions (RewriteCond)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If the request is for `www.website.com/index.php` I want `www.website.com/login/index.php` to be displayed.
But IF the request is for `www.website.com/index.php?any-query` I want `www.website.com/index.php?any-query` to be displayed.
In other words, if the URL contains any query, *it answers exactly that address*. Otherwise everything has to go through *index.php in the /login/ directory*.
I hope I have explained myself more clearly. Thank you.

**EDIT for more clarity**

I explain what the problem looks like. When I click on the tag `<a href="http://www.website.com/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd"></a>` (in the file `/login/index.php`) it responds with `http://www.website.com/login/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd`, instead I would like it to respond exactly with `http://www.website.com/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd`

**EDIT 2 >>> Current /.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login/index.php [R=301,L]
```

**Analysis of current redirects**

The current situation is as follows. When I visit website.com

1. `301    https://website.com/ server_redirect permanent https://website.com/login/index.php`
2. `200    https://website.com/login/index.php`

On the page `/login/index.php` when I click `<a href="http://website.com/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd"></a>`

1. `301    http://website.com/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd server_redirect permanent https://website.com/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd`
2. `200    https://website.com/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd`

When I submit a form in the page `/login/index.php` the link for the SSO is generated (`header("Location: " . $link);`). This is the traffic generated:

1. `302    https://website.com/login/index.php server_redirect temporary https://website.com/index.php?r=adm/sso&login_user=username&time=1000&token=abcde`
2. `302    https://website.com/index.php?r=adm/sso&login_user=username&time=1000&token=abcde server_redirect temporary https://website.com/index.php`
3. `301    https://website.com/index.php server_redirect permanent https://website.com/login/index.php`
4. `200    https://website.com/login/index.php`

**In /login/index.php:**

This is the generation of a link for Single Sign On

```
if (password_verify($password_entered, $password)) {
    $time = time();
    $key = "abcde";
    $token = "abcde";
    $link = "https://www.website.com/index.php?r=adm/sso&login_user=".$user."&time=".$time."&token=".$token;
    header("Location: " . $link);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @anubhava If I comment the Redirect doesn't work the way I want it to anymore

Comment: Only case 3 above is being handled by my suggested rule. Case 1 and 2 are being driven through PHP code. Now please clarify which case is causing trouble and what is desired behavior.

Comment: @anubhava Please see how I modified **Analysis of current redirects**

Comment: I believe your href should be: `<a href="https://website.com/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd"></a>`

Comment: Also case #2 in last section i.e. `302    https://website.com/index.php?r=adm/sso&login_user=username&time=1000&token=abcde server_redirect temporary https://website.com/index.php` is a mystery because shown PHP code is different. There is some other PHP code that is doing this

Comment: No @anubhava, the generated $link works perfectly if I comment what is written in .htaccess. There is no PHP code that does anything else. You simply enter your username and password on the page and the PHP script generates the SSO link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224104/discussion-between-marco987-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple code in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login/index.php [R=301,L]
```

Make sure there is no other rule in this .htaccess and **there is no .htaccess in `login/` directory**.

Comment: Excuse me @anubhava :( The `http://www.website.com/login/index.php?r=adm/lostpwd` link is redirected well. But the following is not: `http://website.com/index.php?r=adm/sso&login_user=xxx&time=xxx&token=abc`

Comment: `http://website.com/index.php?r=adm/sso&login_user=xxx&time=xxx&token=abc` will remain unchanged with above rule. Test in a new browser. Also you can comment here anytime and I would respond, there is no need to remove acceptance mark

Comment: I apologize for the acceptance mark. The last link doesn't work unfortunately. It is not reached with a click on the a tag but with `header("Location: ". $link)` in php

Comment: Sorry but please comment out `header("Location:". $link)` code as we're handling redirects completely in .htaccess. If it is there for specific purpose I suggest you show php code in question and clarify that special logic.

Comment: Please see how I modified **Analysis of current redirects**

Comment: anubhava please, if you can, watch the chat. Thanks

Comment: @marco987: Please post chat link here

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224104/discussion-between-marco987-and-anubhava